# iPhone/Safari: How can I continue to execute javascript while in sleep mode?

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari

Many posts address this for iPhone apps, but I need to know how to do this for javascript on a web page.

My specific problem is that I want to track the device's location over a long period of time (say a car trip). This becomes a problem when the device sleeps (and maybe during a phone call, I haven't tried that case yet).

I'm open to any ideas, including preventing sleep mode (but since I'm in Safari, I'm not sure how much control I'd have to do that).

Comment: I don't know for sure, but doesn't the iPhone stay on when cradled? You could show a pop-up telling users to keep their iphone plugged in; that would solve the car-trip users. As for the rest, you'd be killing their batteries in no time flat. GPS and internet network access really hurt battery life.

Comment: I'm aware of the ramifactions.

The user would be well aware that they are being tracked, it's the exclusive purpose of the webpage. So assume that they will have the webpage up as the frontmost page in Safari, and that Safari is active.

Also I've noticed that a few iterations of "watchPosition" do occur after the device goes to sleep. But after those few (about 5) it stops.

Comment: @Andrew I'll try this in my car. It didn't work in my stereo.

Comment: Also, setting auto-lock to never is a great workaround. Is there a way to set my phone to never auto-lock when docked?

I don't mind asking users to configure their phones this way. Heck I'd *prefer* requiring them to be charging.

Comment: I'm sorry! Now that I look, it seems you can't do it. I got my Touch back with firmware 2.1.2 and I'm certain it had that option ("Stay on while docked: [Yes/No]"), but now, that option is gone. Even plugged in, it shuts off automatically. I wonder why on earth they removed this feature. I've not heard anyone complete about screen burn-in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. Web pages do not execute javascript unless (1) the page is frontmost and (2) Safari is actually active. Safari does not remain active when the device is asleep.

If you think about it, this functionality would be a massive privacy breach. Imagine how you'd feel if you visited a web page that then secretly tracked your location even when your device was off! You'd be very angry. Even if you could do this technologically, people may be upset if they found out you did it.

Location info is closely guarded for reasons of privacy and physical safety (think about stalkers and your web page.) That is why you get a dialog asking to use the Location Manager the first time you get a location.

Comment: I don't think privacy is an issue. Whenever you try to access Location Services in Mobile Safari, doesn't the user have to click "okay"? To me that signifies consent. Well... to me anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though I don't think that it's as much of a privacy breach as you suggest. The user's always informed and should have no expectation that "sleep" is the same as "off". But that's a matter of opinion I guess.

Comment: I would be concerned by any remote scripting that could activate such the location manager. Given security issues with web sites, you couldn't even be sure that the site you thought was requesting your location was actually sending the code. Having a web page that ran and tracked your location in the background would be even more dangerous even if you had to give it permission to start. How many pages do you have loaded right now in mobile Safari and how long have they been there? It would be easy to open an hole and leave it open.

Comment: Since this thread is old, thought I would update my findings. You can in fact execute javascript and respond to server requests, but if any of those are in a setTimeout, they will not execute.