# Javascript stops as I lock iphone, can it still run?

Tags: javascript, iphone

Is there a way to tell a javascript function to continue running even as a phone is locked?

Pretty much I have a timer that I need to continue to run even as the phone is set to idle.

Comment: Is the javascript in your own application (i.e. in a `UIWebView`), or in a browser on the phone (Safari or similar)?

Comment: it's a web app, so in a browser

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can even run a JavaScript when the safari is in the background.

Just put a hidden frame on your site:

```
<iframe src="background.html" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

background.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" />
</head>
<body>
<script>
parent.run_function_from_core_page();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The page in the hidden frame refreshes every 3 seconds, and run the JavaScript, even if the phone is locked.

Be careful because it can lead to high data traffic also if you are not on WiFi!

Comment: I just tested it out on an iPhone 4s running iOS 6.0.1, and it seems to work fine. Great find!

Comment: This works as written on iPhone 4S with iOS 7.02 (11A501). :) @blabus, I suggest you retry or post your code.

Comment: I've tried this with iOS 7.12 and have seen that the refresh stops after three minutes or so.. once the phone has been locked.. thus killing the app..

Comment: @HarshaRama Yes, this is not sufficient to keep a timer through phone locking/backgrounding. You have to go native for that. I did also observe this refresh stopping arbitrarily. So this timer will work for a short undefined period of time and is overall not reliable.

Comment: As of today (April 4, 2017) the accepted answer (about iFrames) no longer seems to be working on Chrome 55 on Android 6.0.1 -- the iFrame only executes JavaScript when the parent page has focus.  Switching tabs in Chrome is enough to stop the execution.

Answer (score 14):

**EDIT**: You can run timed javascript code in the background using the `<iframe>` trick. See [Zsolt's response to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7785732/770938).

You cannot continue to run javascript while the iPhone is sleeping using `setTimeout()`, however.

When the phone is put to sleep, Safari will kill any running javascript processes using `setTimeout()`. Check out [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174862/iphone-safari-how-can-i-continue-to-execute-javascript-while-in-sleep-mode/3174886#3174886) for some reasons why this is done.

Comment: ok so say I have to make a timer for a web app and need it to run even when the phone is locked, how should I do this do you think?

It could be done in PHP? and then the javascript could just be displaying it perhaps?

Comment: JavaScript still runs when the page is not the active tab but safari is still open.

Comment: Safari will not kill javascript process using `setTimeout()` but pause the operation that resumes automatically when the device is awake.

Answer (score 4):

Nope. When the phone is locked and goes to sleep, your code will not run. This is by design; iOS devices are essentially cell phones, not full-fledged PCs, and are designed to save power when the user is not using them.