# Web-app running Javascript when device (phone, tablet) is locked

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web-applications

Is there a way to update "added to homescreen" bookmarks on android and iOs devices?

The goal is to update the info while the user has access to internet and then have the info available offline, without the user having to do it manually.

I tested the [iFrame technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047989/javascript-stops-as-i-lock-iphone-can-it-still-run) but it didn't work.