# Geolocation fail in case of inactive mobile browser

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am using following code:

```
var fail = function(error) {
  alert("Unable to get location");
};

function getGeo() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        success,
      fail,
      {maximumAge: 50000, timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
  }
};
```

Mostly It works but often it gives geolocation error and unable to get coordinates.

How can I make possible to get coordinates no matter browser window is inactive or browser is in background or mobile itself in sleep mode?

Comment: Did you have a look at this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576265/allow-html5-web-app-to-access-location-when-browser-isnt-focused-ios

Answer (score 1):

Without specifics of "geolocation error" my answer can no be complete but: -

At present you cannot get coordinates if browser window is inactive or browser is in background or mobile itself in sleep mode, unless you are developing a hybrid App with something like phonegap/cordova. (Firefox has the exception of continuing to service watchPosition() *if* the App is foregrounded but the phone is asleep.)

I have made several suggestions to W3C, IETF, Chrome Dev, Mozilla Dev, and Edge Dev regarding a workable solution using the [Service Worker Extensibility](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#extensibility) functionality for a Javascript-only solution.

Briefly, the UA tracks Geolocation changes and if within range of a dev supplied filter, a ServiceWorker will be instantiated which may foreground the App or merely notify the App Server.

*Please* pursue this issue with the relevant bodies as the idea is beginning to gain traction.

HTH